# Print only unique lines from file not the duplicates

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl

I have a sorted words list, line by line file like so:

```
apple
apple
grapes
lime
orange
orange
pear
pear
peach
strawberry
strawberry
```

I only want to print out unique lines and drop duplicates:

```
grapes
peach
lime
```

How can I do this with `sed`, `awk` or `perl`?

Answer (score 10):

That's the job for [uniq](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html):

```
$ LC_ALL=C uniq -u file
grapes
lime
peach
```

If you want other tools, like `perl`:

```
perl -nle '$h{$_}++; END {print for grep { $h{$_} == 1 } %h}' <file
```

Comment: Why are you using `-l` ? Also the `for` after  the print is not needed if you remove the `-l`, because you aren't pointlessly stripping newlines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35503/discussion-between-cuonglm-and-123).

Answer (score 1):

Try this AWK!

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (x in a) if (a[x] == 1) print x}'
```

Comment: No, that still leaves the duplicate words, I want to print the only uniq words contained in the file.

Comment: @MIlle82 UPS!! I hadn't understood your question!!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{arr[$1]++} END {for (i in arr) {if (arr[i]==1) {print i} }}' 1
grapes
lime
peach
```