# grep lines that exists on one file but not in the other

Tags: linux, command-line, sed, grep

I'm trying to do simple `grep` and `grep -v` so I will get the lines from `a.txt` that exists in `b.txt` and not in `c.txt`.

#### Example of 3 files

`a.txt`:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

`up.txt`:

```
a.up
b.up
c.up
```

`dw.txt`:

```
a.dw
b.dw
```

Desired output:

```
c
```

I wrote the below code but the `grep` looks on the `$(sed...)`  as one single line at a time and not as a whole:

```
sed 's/.up//' /tmp/b.txt | grep -f /tmp/a.txt | grep -vf $(sed 's/.dw//' /tmp/c.txt)
```

Comment: have you tried diff? (`kdiff3` is a visual tool, not for streaming/scripts, there are other diff tools, including `diff`). a 3way diff tool will do best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the files are all sorted and that we're using a shell that understands process substitutions (like `bash`):

```
$ join -t . -v 1 -o 0 <( join -t . a.txt b.txt ) c.txt
c
```

or, for other shells,

```
$ join -t . a.txt b.txt | join -t . -v 1 -o 0 - c.txt
c
```

This uses `join` twice to perform relational joins between the files.  The data is interpreted as dot-delimited fields (with `-t .`).

The join between `a.txt` and `b.txt` is straight forward and produces

```
a.up
b.up
c.up
```

These are all the lines from the two files whose first dot-delimited field occurs in both files. The output consists of the join field (`a`, `b`, `c`) followed by the other fields from both files (only `b.txt` has any further data).

The second join is a bit more special.  With `-v 1` we ask to see the entries in the first file (the intermediate result above) that can't be paired with any line in the second file, `c.txt`.  Additionally, we only ask to see the join field itself (`-o 0`). Without the `-o` flag, we would get `c.up` as the result.

---

If the files are not sorted, then each occurance of a filename `file` could be replaced by `<( sort file )` in the command.

Answer (score 4):

With single fast GNU **`awk`** command:

```
awk -F'.' \
'{
     if (ARGIND == 1) a[$1];
     else if (ARGIND == 2 && $1 in a) comm[$1];
     else if (ARGIND == 3){
         delete a;
         if ($1 in comm) delete comm[$1]
     }
 }
 END{ for (i in comm) print i }' a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

The output:

```
c
```

---

- `-F'.'` - treat `.` as field separator
- `ARGIND` - The index in `ARGV`(array of command line arguments) of the current file being processed
- `comm` - array of *common* items between first 2 files (`a.txt` and `b.txt`)

Comment: good one, is ARGIND common for all awk or specific to gawk, etc? you could also reverse the order of files to avoid deleting from array and having to use END... `if (ARGIND == 1) c[$1]; else if (ARGIND == 2 && !($1 in c)) b[$1]; else if (ARGIND == 3 && $1 in b){ print }`

Comment: @Sundeep, it's GNU extension

Answer (score 2):

## comm

Assuming the files are sorted, and duplicate lines removed:

```
comm -12 a.txt <(cut -d. -f1 b.txt) | comm -23 - <(cut -d. -f1 c.txt)
```

This is written for Ubuntu, using Bash and GNU utilities, but hopefully it works for other OS's.

#### Explanation

- `comm -12` Print the lines that both files share (read `man comm` for details)
- `<(...)` Process substitution - Use a command in place of an input file
- `cut -d. -f1` For each line, remove everything after the first dot
- `comm -23` Print the lines that are unique to the first file
- `-` Read from stdin instead of a file

Answer (score 2):

If the files given are sorted and there are no internal duplicates, use this:

```
$ comm -12 a.txt <(sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' up.txt) | comm -23 - <(sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' dw.txt)
```

In shells that have Process Substitution (`<(…)`). For other shells read below.

---

What you describe in this sentence:

> get the lines from a.txt that exists in b.txt and not in c.txt

could be reduced to the set operations:

```
( a intersect b ) complement c
```

There are several ways to execute set operations on files, [many are listed on this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11667/265604)

I like the way the command `comm` could perform most operations.
But the files you present are not the clean set to use. The extensions need to be erased/removed. The generic way to remove the extensions with sed is:

```
$ sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' file
```

So, the two clean files will be created with:

```
$ sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' up.txt > up.txt.clean
$ sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' dw.txt > dw.txt.clean
```

With those two files, a one-liner solution is:

```
$ comm -12 a.txt up.txt.clean | comm -23 - dw.txt.clean
c
```

Or, doing `( up.txt complement dw.txt) intersect a.txt`:

```
$ comm -23 up.txt.clean dw.txt.clean | comm -12 - a.txt
c
```

Both commands could be implemented directly from original files in some shells with:

```
$ comm -12 a.txt <(sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' up.txt) | comm -23 - <(sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' dw.txt)
```

If the process substitution is not available it is possible to use only one file as follows:

```
$ sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' up.txt | comm -12 a.txt - >result1.txt
$ sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' dw.txt | comm -23 result1.txt -
c
$ rm result1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -f a.txt <(cut -d '.' -f 1 up.txt) > common.txt
$ grep -vf <(cut -d '.' -f 1 dw.txt) common.txt
```

Compares first word between 2 files and writes to matching word to `common.txt`.
Compares `dw.txt` with `common.txt` and print inverted match ie. 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F\\. -lane '
   $h{@ARGV}{$F[0]}++,next if @ARGV;
   print if exists $h{2}{$_} && !exists $h{1}{$_};
' up.txt dw.txt a.txt
```

Build up the hash %h with top level keys as "2" and "1", with 2 referring to the first argument (up.txt), 1 referring to dw.txt. For the data given, the hash structure would look something like:(the order could differ)

```
%h = (
   1 => { a => 1, b => 1, },
   2 => { a => 1, b => 1, c => 1, },
);
```

as can be seen there are two mini-hashes inside the main hash %h. So when the time comes to read in the third argument (a.txt), we make the decision to print the record based on whether that record can be seen (as a key) in  the mini-hash %2 AND not seen in the mini-hash %1, inside the main hash %h (also referred to as a hash-of-hashes, or HoH).

Answer (score 0):

A variation of [Roman's answer](/a/454143/72456) and to make it simpler:

```
gawk -F. 'ARGIND==1{ seen[$1]; next } 
         ARGIND==2{ delete seen[$1]; next }
         ($1 in seen)
' fileUP fileDW fileA
```

- This `ARGIND==1{ seen[$1]; next }` holding the first column of *fileUP* into an associated array named `seen`.
- This `ARGIND==2{ delete seen[$1]; next }` deletes those exist in *fileDW*.
- and this `($1 in seen)` prints remained ones when it's also exist in *fileA*

Answer (score -1):

Here's another alternative using that's similar to yours using: `grep`, `sort` & `uniq`, and `sed`.

```
$ sed 's/\.\(dw\|up\)//' up.txt dw.txt | grep -xFf a.txt | sort | uniq -u
c
```

This works by producing a list of matches for each of the files `up.txt` and `dw.txt` using `a.txt` as a input file to `grep`. This produces output like this:

```
$ sed 's/\.\(dw\|up\)//' up.txt dw.txt | grep -xFf a.txt
a
b
c
a
b
```

The key details here are that we're:

- using `sed` to chop off any trailing extensions from the 2 files `up.txt` and `dw.txt`
- With extensions deleted, we then use `grep` to filter any corresponding matches from `a.txt`
- The matching that we tell `grep` to perform is exact, `-x`
- The `-F` tells `grep` to treat the patterns in `a.txt` as fixed strings

With the above output in hand, you can simply run this through `sort` and then use `uniq` to get only the the lines that do not repeat.

#### References

- Stephane comment#14 - [Bug 18927 - Different strings should never collate as equal](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18927#c13)
- [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do)
- [Print only unique lines from file not the duplicates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261007/print-only-unique-lines-from-file-not-the-duplicates)
- [The Open Group Base Specifications man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uniq.html)